# How i select a specific variable from a pandas.core.frame.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to select a specific date in these DataFrames. I want to select just the date `2021-09-03`(and see the adj close and the signal) how I can do this? and also I want to don't see the DataFrame that doesn't have the date that I want.

I'm trying to see this in this code and the DataFrame that give us the code `df.buyingSignals()` are the 2 tables down the code:

```
acciones=['FCEL','CAT']
for accion in acciones:
    accion=Ticker(accion, "2021-1-1", "2021-9-20", [5, 10, 20])
    accion.buyingSignals()
    #np.where(accion.loc['2021-9-03'],accion.buyingSignals(),0) #Possible answer that i think but it's not working
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed


 ********** FCEL **********
            Adj Close  Signal
Date                         
2021-02-02  21.430000       1
2021-02-09  27.959999       1
2021-06-02  10.430000       1
2021-08-31   6.240000       1
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed


 ********** CAT **********
             Adj Close  Signal
Date                          
2021-02-19  207.849991       1
2021-03-11  217.603302       1
2021-04-01  230.455948       1
2021-04-20  225.396088       1
2021-05-04  232.164093       1
2021-05-10  241.314987       1
2021-05-17  243.483337       1
2021-05-19  235.605621       1
2021-06-09  233.397476       1
2021-07-15  210.281525       1
2021-08-13  218.570007       1
2021-08-31  210.869995       1
2021-09-03  210.369995       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `loc`:

```
>>> df.loc['2021-09-03']
Adj Close    210.369995
Signal         1.000000
Name: 2021-09-03, dtype: float64
>>>
```

Comment: You are right, sorry i didn't make the right question for my problem. Now i edit it, anyway thanks.